# QAction aware of the item where the context menu containing it is triggered in a QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a QTableView/QAbstractTableModel framework where I implemented a context menu, with at most 2 actions, depending on the index where the menu was requested. For one of those two actions, once triggered I would like to emit the index where the context menu was requested. I have a solution that works but I don't like it.

The code:

```
class MyModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    ...

    def _restore_all(self):
        print('restore all')

    def _restore_index(self, index):
        print('restore index at: row = ' , index.row(), ', column = ', index.column())
    ...

class _ItemAwareAction(QAction):

    _mytriggered = pyqtSignal('QModelIndex')

    def __init__(self, *args, index=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._index = index
        self.triggered.connect(self._emit_index)

    def _emit_index(self):
        self._mytriggered.emit(self._index)

class MyTableView(QTableView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        model = MyModel(self)
        self.setModel(model)
        # Attributes
        restore_all_action = QAction('Restore all values', self)
        self._restore_all_action = restore_all_action
        self._menu = QMenu(self)
        # Connexions
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self._item_context_menu)
        restore_all_action.triggered.connect(model._restore_all)

    def _item_context_menu(self, pos):
        menu = self._menu
        menu.clear()
        index = self.indexAt(pos)
        model = self.model()
        originals = model._originals
        if not originals:
            return
        menu.addAction(self._restore_all_action)
        references = model._index_to_references(index)
        if references in originals:
            action = _ItemAwareAction(
                'Restore this value', parent=self, index=index
            )
            action._mytriggered.connect(model._restore_index)
            menu.addAction(action)
        menu.popup(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos))
    ...
```

I find my `_ItemAwareAction` class to be an unnecessary loop. Maybe you can point me to a simpler and more straightforward solution.

Comment: Use [menu.exec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#exec-1), which executes synchronously, and returns the action that was clicked (or None). That way, `index` is still available in the current scope. Or do `action.triggered.connect(lambda: model._restore_index(index))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler solution would be to use lambda or partials:

```py
    def _item_context_menu(self, pos):
        # ...
        if references in originals:
            action = QAction('Restore this value', parent=self)
            action.triggered.connect(lambda: model._restore_index(index))
        # ...
```

Since you're not doing cycles of sort, you could even just check if the triggered action is the one that should reset, and that's accomplished by using `exec()` (which blocks until the menu is triggered/closed) instead of returning immediately:

```py
    def _item_context_menu(self, pos):
        # ...
        if references in originals:
            restoreAction = QAction('Restore this value', parent=self)
        else:
            # cancelled menu returns None, we need to compare with something else
            restoreAction = -1
        if menu.exec_(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos)) == restoreAction:
            model._restore_index(index)
```

Another alternative is to use the [`data()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#data) of the action, and then you either connect to the menu `triggered` action.

```py
class MyTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        self._menu = QMenu(self)
        self._menu.triggered.connect(self._menu_triggered)

    def _menu_triggered(self, action):
        if isinstance(action.data(), QtCore.QModelIndex):
            self.model()._restore_index(action.data())

    def _item_context_menu(self, pos):
        # ...
        if references in originals:
            action = QAction('Restore this value', parent=self)
            action.setData(index)
        # ...
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your proposals. I'm not a big fan of anonymous functions or synchronous executions with `exec`. So I chose to do `action.setData(index)`, but I didn't implement your `_menu_triggered` method, instead I removed the index argument from the `MyModel._restore_index` method and kept only `self` and to get the index I do `index = self.sender().data()`.

Comment: @JonFranco consider that `exec` is only blocking for calls executed from the ContextMenu event (which is what triggers the `customContextMenuRequested` signal), but won't prevent event processing for the main Qt loop (it actually executes a private QEventLoop, just like QDialog); in fact it's very common even in Qt sources. Be also aware that using `self.sender()` is not always safe (but, at least in this simple scenario and as long as threading is not involved, it should be).

Comment: @musicamente you are absolutely right, I was not aware of this, it's clearly stated in the docs, thanks.